# Literature on PAA for Rates products

Tags: fixed-income, pnl, pl-attribution

There is abundant literature on pricing interest rate derivatives, but it is a struggle to find much on the science and methods behind practical Profit Attribution Analysis (PnL explain) on fixed income portfolios, or portfolios in any asset class in general.

Is there a comprehensive book which covers this topic?

Comment: Some discussion of references for PnL Explain here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59354/good-references-on-pnl-explain

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I recommend: [Fixed Income Portfolio Analytics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-12667-8) by David Jamieson Bolder (ex-BIS); take a look at Part III in particular but the whole book is interesting, useful, and very well written IMHO.

Comment: Part III Attribution of Bolder's book is a decent introduction to risk-theoretical P&L attribution for bonds.